# How can i extract a dynamic string/word from a website using Java

Tags: java, html, parsing

Hello everyone here is my problem.

I want to extract 2 words from a website, the words are "won" or "loss". If i can find those 2 words on  the website i will be able to write the program i am working on.The problems i have are...

1. When i write a java program to get the html code from the site it only gives me the html code that is not changing ie: it doesnt giving the dynamic php code parts.
2. When i "inspect elements" on the website it gives me exactly what i want. It says i either won or loss in the html tags . However if i simply view source it doesn't show me that dynamic php code that u would see when inspecting elements.
3. Is there a way for me to write code that looks at "inspect elements" for the website and keep track of the part of the html code that is changing between "win"  or "loss"?

Answer (score 0):

I've had trouble with something like this before and since you lack details I will give you the best answer I can...

More information that will be helpful to know maybe if you edit include,

- Code... Show me what you got
- The html code
- APIs or frameworks used in you application

So the issue seems like when you request the site the information is not there. Normally this doesn't happen since most webpage display information at load time.

These days we do a lot of stuff with Javascript so therefore that is probably the part you are having problems with. Javascript can load information onto the page dynamically at anytime. It need not me at load time and even if it looks like it by eye that its there when the page loads it may not be since it's too fast to notice.

Look into the javascript code and see if you can find a get, post, or put action and see if you can follow that to where it loads the page. Then mimic the request in your program.

Comment: There are 3 places on the website that shows where i won or loss. i see 3 places so far. a way for me to read directly off the webpage, a way for me to read directly off inspect element, or through reading from the network tab in the inspect elements  thing. Out of those 3 ways of seeing if i won or loss is there a way to store that value into my java program to determine if i win or loss?

Comment: @DaneelD What kind of code did you write reading the html? Or are you asking for a way to parse the html for those 3 values? In case you need a list of APIs for web parsing http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2861/options-for-html-scraping

Comment: I dont know how else to explain my problem i wrote quick code to prove that ime not getting the dynamic javascript/php/data that shows up after you log in or after you do a action. It gives me back the code of root website and not the website ime currently on with my personalized information.---http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqp07----I set a counter that keeps track of the number of hrefs before and after i do a action on a website and it doesnt change